# Installing Topology Manager fails by ERROR_INVALID_MEMBER

Tags: web8.5, topology-manager, installation

When I installing SDL Web8.5 by using the installer, following error occurs during installing Topology Manager.

> A new member could not be added to a local group because of the member
>   has the wrong account type.

The CMS Server is belonging to Active Directory domain, and the CMS server itself is a Domain Controller. Is it possible this fact is affecting?
And how can I avoid this error?

The more detailed log message is following.

> SFXCA: Extracting custom action to temporary directory:
>   C:\Windows\Installer\MSI62B.tmp-\ SFXCA: Binding to CLR version
>   v4.0.30319 Calling custom action
>   CommonCustomActions!CommonCustomActions.WindowsGroupCustomActions.CreateGroupExecute
>   Begin CreateGroupExecute CreateGroup: Unable to find the group
>   'devcms01\Topology Manager Users'. Creating new... CreateGroup: Unable
>   to find the group 'devcms01\Topology Manager Service Users'. Creating
>   new... CreateGroup: Unable to find the group 'devcms01\Topology
>   Manager Administrators'. Creating new... AddToGroup: Checking if User
>   'takt01' is a member of 'Topology Manager Administrators' AddToGroup:
>   User 'takt01' is not member of 'Topology Manager Administrators'.
>   Adding... Execute application 'net' with arguments 'localgroup
>   "Topology Manager Administrators" "takt01" /add'
>   RunCmdToolToAddToGroup: result '0' AddToGroup: Checking if child group
>   'NETWORK SERVICE' is a member of 'Topology Manager Administrators'
>   AddToGroup: Child group 'NETWORK SERVICE' is not member of 'Topology
>   Manager Administrators'. Adding... Execute application 'net' with
>   arguments 'localgroup "Topology Manager Administrators" "NETWORK
>   SERVICE" /add' Application return an exit code 2 with next error:
>   System error 1388 occured.
>
> A new member could not be added to a local group because the member
>   has the wrong account type.
>
> RunCmdToolToAddToGroup: result '2' AddToGroup: Checking if child group
>   'Administrators' is a member of 'Topology Manager Administrators'
>   AddToGroup: Child group 'Administrators' is not member of 'Topology
>   Manager Administrators'. Adding... Execute application 'net' with
>   arguments 'localgroup "Topology Manager Administrators"
>   "Administrators" /add' Application return an exit code 2 with next
>   error: System error 1388 occured.
>
> A new member could not be added to a local group because the member
>   has the wrong account type.
>
> RunCmdToolToAddToGroup: result '2' AddToGroup: Checking if child group
>   'Users' is a member of 'Topology Manager Users' AddToGroup: Child
>   group 'Users' is not member of 'Topology Manager Users'. Adding...
>   Execute application 'net' with arguments 'localgroup "Topology Manager
>   Users" "Users" /add' Application return an exit code 2 with next
>   error: System error 1388 occured.
>
> A new member could not be added to a local group because the member
>   has the wrong account type.
>
> RunCmdToolToAddToGroup: result '2' AddToGroup: Checking if child group
>   'SYSTEM' is a member of 'Topology Manager Service Users' AddToGroup:
>   Child group 'SYSTEM' is not member of 'Topology Manager Service
>   Users'. Adding... Execute application 'net' with arguments 'localgroup
>   "Topology Manager Service Users" "SYSTEM" /add' Application return an
>   exit code 2 with next error: System error 1388 occured.
>
> A new member could not be added to a local group because the member
>   has the wrong account type.
>
> RunCmdToolToAddToGroup: result '2' AddToGroup: Checking if child group
>   'NETWORK SERVICE' is a member of 'Topology Manager Service Users'
>   AddToGroup: Child group 'NETWORK SERVICE' is not member of 'Topology
>   Manager Service Users'. Adding... Execute application 'net' with
>   arguments 'localgroup "Topology Manager Service Users" "NETWORK
>   SERVICE" /add' Application return an exit code 2 with next error:
>   System error 1388 occured.
>
> A new member could not be added to a local group because the member
>   has the wrong account type.

Comment: Is that user which you trying to install is it has local admin rights on the machine?

Comment: The user who does installation is Active Directory user, and it belongs to Administrators group which is buit-in Active Directory group. I started installer by 'Run as administrator'. Also CMS server itself joins in an AD's domain. Is it still necessary to use local administrator user to install?

Comment: I have heard about installation issues when trying to install on a Domain Controller, indeed. In general, this is considered a bad practice.

Comment: I asked SDL support about this issue, they say it's impossible to install SDL Web into Domain Controller server, unfortunately.

Comment: Please Answer your own Question, in that case.

Answer (score 3):

I asked SDL support about this issue, they say it's impossible to install SDL Web into Domain Controller server, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you mark this as the correct answer please?